# Unable to post form data using axios in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i am working with Reactjs and i am using nextjs framework,Right now i am trying to post "Formdata"
using "axios" but unable to get anything in server(api side),I tried with 2 different way

```
var emails=email;
      var passwords=password;

      const data = {
        email: emails,
        password: passwords
      };
```

I tried with following way

```
 axios.post('https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/email-monitor/api/testinfo3/', data).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
      })
```

I tried with following code also but not working for me

```
formData.append('email', emails);
formData.append('password', password);

const response = await axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/email-monitor/api/testinfo3/",
    data: FormData,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
  }).then(function (response) {
     alert(response);
    }).catch(function (error) {
    alert('error is ' + error);
    });
```

Comment: When something is "not working for me", you should tell us what exactly is not working. Is it erroring out? If so, what kind of errors? Is it skipped or is it not run at all or.. you get the idea.

Comment: @technophyle understand! i am getting nothing in api side ( php) , unable to post data , data is not getting in server side , hope you understand my point

Comment: What do you see in the Network tab?

Comment: @technophyle i am getting empty array
array()

Comment: Have you tried to replace:

`data: FormData,`

with 

`data: formData,`

Comment: Can you post some server-side code?

Comment: @TheKNVB its working now Thank you so much , my second code is working but can you tell me that why not my first code not working for me

Comment: Maybe you haven't provided the header. I am not sure.

Comment: As @TheKNVB pointed out you were sending the built in `FormData` object (capital F) and not your instance of the formdata `formData`

Comment: I think your first code is not working because of the missing headers. `axios.post(url,  data , config)` provide the config parameter where you can add the `content-type` headers.